# Intersection between a function and a rectangle

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a real function such that $ f(x) > 0 $ in $[a,b]$. How does calculate the area  under the curve $f(x)$ delimited by the rectangle $[a,b] \times [0,c]$, for $c>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $ g(x) =  \min\{f(x),c\}$  then  $$ area = \int_a^b g(x) dx $$

Comment: Yeah! This is correct, but we have to know the intersection points between $f(x)$ and the line $h(x)=c$. Does exist any method to avoid the calculation of these points?